# How to get neo4j query result returned from .then with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I would need to get the data returned by using the Neo4j driver for Node JS. My problem is, that i can print the value of 'online' out on console *inside* the .then call but i can't seem to get access to it outside of that part - I have tried returning `record.get('onl')`, assign it to a pre-defined variable outside the function but nothing works - all i get as result if i try to, for example, print the value of `online` out at the last line in this snippet, is `Promise { <pending> }`. I suppose I don't do the promise handling right, and I looked up lots of tutorials and examples, but I can't work it out. So: how could i assign the returned data `(record.get('onl'))` to `var online` and get actual result instead of the promise?
Thanks in advance :)

```
var online = session.run(cyp1, param).then(results => {
                return  results.records.map(record =>{
                    console.log(record.get('onl'))
                    return record.get('onl')                    
            })
            }).then(()=>{
                session.close()
        });
console.log(online)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are assigning var `online` as a 'Promise Chain' & not a 'Resolved Promise'. You could use [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await) this will allow you to write async code in a synchronous manner.

```js
async function getRecords(){
    const records = await session.run(cyp1, param);

    return records.map(record => record.get('onl'))
}

const online = await getRecords();
```

> Use try/catch/finally

```js
try {
   const online = await getRecords();
} catch (error) {
   // do something
} finally {
   await session.close()
}
```

**If you wanted to continue using `.then()`**
You need to use 'Promise Chaining' and pass the value 'Down the chain', this results in complex 'Callback'/'Promise Chain' hell.

```js
session.run(cyp1, param).then(results => {
    return results.records.map(record => record.get('onl'))
}).then((online)=> {
    console.log(online)
}).catch(() => {
    // do something
}).finally(() => {
    session.close()
});
```